# Как сделать, чтобы один блок уменьшал with другого блока при изменении ширины окна?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

**Здравствуйте!** 
Имеется два блока. 
Материнскому, в который они входят, прописано значение `display: flex;`.
Каждому из дочерних блоков прописано свойство, идущее от материнского `flex-direction: row;` и отдельно им `with: 50%;`
Как сделать, чтобы при измненении ширины окна, блок, который справа, уменьшал `with` левого?

 **Спасибо!**

Comment: А изначально как они делят пространства?

Comment: @Air друг под другом

Comment: Возможно тебе подойдёт свойство flex-shrink для левого элемента. Посмотри [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink).

Comment: Как они могут быть друг под другом, если у родителя `flex-direction: row` ?

Comment: @Air так вы спросили,как они "изначально". С параметром 'flex-direction: row' они как и пологается - в строку, а изначально друг под другом. Или я не правильно понял суть вопроса?

Comment: Если честно, вообще  не понял что именно тебе надо... Лучше нарисуй)))

Comment: @Air https://youtu.be/nT8XKUvc1_M Нужно, чтобы блок с картой сокращал блок с контактами. Как это сделать?

Comment: @Air может это можно как-то `calc` решить?

Comment: Код должен быть **прямо в тексте вопроса** без ссылок на сторонние ресурсы (кроме разве что библиотек)

Comment: Ну на видео более понятно.)))  Хотя интуитивно догадывался о чем ты. Задай блоку с картой фиксированную ширину, а блоку с контактами можно в процентах. Сложно ответить не видя, что у тя творится в разметке. Тут `flex` не нужен, так как даже при фиксированной ширине карты родитель будет воздействовать на дочерний элемент. В общем без разметки сложно сказать. Слушай не забывай о внутренних отступах `(padding)`, а то на видео у тя выглядит ужасно.